# Adding info to an exception

Tags: java, exception

I'd like to add information to a stack trace/exception.

Basically I've got something like this as of now, which I really like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.so.main(SO.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
```

However I'd like to catch that exception and add additional info to it, while still having the original stack trace.

For example, I'd like to have that:

```
Exception in thread "main" CustomException: / by zero (you tried to divide 42 by 0)
    at com.so.main(SO.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
```

So basically I want to catch the ArithmeticException and rethrow, say, a CustomException (adding *"you tried to divide 42 by 0"* in this example) while still keeping the stacktrace from the original ArithmeticException.

What is the correct way to do this in Java?

Is the following correct:

```
try {
     ....
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
     throw new CustomException( "You tried to divide " + x + " by " + y, e );
}
```

Comment: How would you possibly know the specifics of the exception if you weren't the one that threw it?

Comment: @Falmarri: I don't know the specificities, but I can add additional infos, like method parameters.  I added an example at the end of my question.

Comment: Usually this information is only useful for debugging. You can also try using the debugger to debug your program and place a breakpoint on the exception.  When the exception is thrown you will see the conditions which caused it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can nest exceptions like that in Java, as of Java 1.4. I do this all the time. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html.

When someone prints the stack trace from your custom exception, it'll show both the `CustomException` stack trace and the stack trace of the nested `ArithmeticException`. You can nest arbitrarily deeply.

Comment: +1, thanks a lot.  Interesting to see that it's there since a long time :)

Comment: Link died [Sad face]

Comment: This was a helpful answer. I was already aware that you could nest exceptions within each other, but I didn't understand that if you wanted to include information in the deeply-nested exceptions, that this was already done for you. I noticed that in the printed stack trace, the message for each exception is printed after the exception's name. For example: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you tried to divide 1.0 by 0.` I was used to Go programming where you have to include this information yourself in the string you create for each error as you return wrapped errors.

Answer (score 14):

You could also do this :

```
try {
     ....
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
     ArithmeticException ae = new ArithmeticException( "You tried to divide " + x + " by " + y+" "+e.getMessage());
     ae.setStackTrace(e.getStackTrace());
     throw ae;
}
```

Which would give you "invisible" exceptions :-)

Update [27-september-2012] :

In Java 7: another cool trick is:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    e.addSuppressed(new ArithmeticException( "You tried to divide " + x + " by " + y));
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: +1 too... By "invisible", you mean that there will only be one stack trace and not two?

Comment: I cannot edit your answer (I don't have enough rep) but I think you cut/paste and left the *", e"* that you should remove at the end of the line where you create the ArithmeticException.

Comment: Yes there will be only 1 stacktrace. And thanks for noticing the error.

Comment: I cannot edit your answer because I don't have enough rep *and* because it is not my answer.  You have only 667 rep but you can always edit your own answer, so you can fix it if you want :)

Comment: So, does the e.addSuppressed with the same type of exception does the same, like the upper code block?
As I just want to add some additional info to the message of the exception and keep the Stacktrace the same. Thx!